# Append values dynamically without page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, expressionengine

I want to create a variable value by appending two different values **without page reloading**

Code:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="blending_log"  return="sthome/blending/ENTRY_ID"}
<h3>Select and enter data</h3>

{!--------Receive data to create value--------}
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="" />
<br /><br />
Organic Or Conventional:
{field:org_con}

Agent Number:
{field:agent_number}

{!-----END Receive data to create lot number-------}
```

field type Organic or conventional is a select box.
User can select O (Organic) OR C (Conventional) 
Agent Number is a text field user enter something like 018.
As soon as user select O OR C from  Organic or conventional 
and entered Agent number it should append value in hidden field.

eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="O018" />
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="C018" />
```

**This should happen without page reloading**

I googled and tried some JavaScript and Ajax codes.
But never work.
Sorry, I am a JavaScript and Ajax Noob.

Any help please.

Comment: So to be clear, you have a select box with O or C options. You have a text box that the user enters a number, and when they choose either O or C, and enter a number you want a concatenation of both to be the value of the hidden field?

Comment: Yes OJay exactly that is what I want to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to use [SafeCracker's dynamic_title parameter](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#dynamic-title):

```
{exp:safecracker channel="blending_log" return="sthome/blending/ENTRY_ID" dynamic_title="[org_con][agent_number]"}
```

You can then remove your hidden "title" input.

Comment: Dear Derek Hogue, Thank you, Thank you, THANK YOU.  Excellent code. Please let me know if you have books or any other materials published by you about ExpressionEngine.  I will buy all of them.  my email: compvidya@gmail.com  **Thank you very much**

Comment: Dear Derek, I want to add [current_time format="%y%m%d%H%i"] like dynamic_title="[org_con][agent_number][current_time format="%y%m%d%H%i"]"   Is there a way to do that?  Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="C018" id="newVal"/>
```

This can be used to set the value

```
document.getElementById("newVal").value="newValue";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  But, problem is the code use ExpressionEngine so I have to append like value="{O or C}{Agent No}"

Answer (score 1):

Give the hidden field an Id eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="" id="hiddenField"/>
```

then I would assume that you want the value of the hidden field to be after they fill out the number
(although you could check if both are filled out before adding the value to the hidden field)

```
**jQuery**
$('#Id_of_agent_number_HTMLElement').change(function () {
    $('#hiddenField').val($('#Id_of_org_con_HTMLElement').val() + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Dear OJay.  It dosen't work.  I get this error message: The form you submitted contained the following errors

    The Title field is required. I believe since this code is on ExpressionEngine with safecracker we have to fill the value before we send the form

Comment: Means that the code didn't work, primarily I would say becuase of the html ids. Do you have the actual html that is rendered, and not the expressionengine markup, as the jQuery will be intereacting with the HTML

Comment: Dear OJay, Thanks for help.  I will check original html (By using page source) and let you know